# Is there a maximum number of documents that can be retrieved in a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, continuations

I am using a stored procedure in Cosmos DB with continuation. When I call it with a filter included to return ~<1000 documents it works, in batches of whatever I set the pageSize to. When I try to retrieve more, I get an error for the isAccepted value from the collection.queryDocuments. I am looking to retrieve a lot of documents to perform an aggregate calculation on them (~64k). Does Cosmos DB limit the total number of documents that a stored procedure can work with, and if so, is there a way to increase this?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Alan

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could refer this [MSDN threa](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98ff6cf4-f943-45f5-a14b-58eb77df2729/documentdb-updating-multiple-documents-fails?forum=azurecosmosdb)d, this might give you more insight on how you can achieve what you are trying to do.